# Can't find object's location in array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I have a view controller in which athletes can be evaluated. There is a next button in the navigation bar that should load the next athlete. I am trying to step through my array with the following code but every single time the index returns as 2? I have no idea why! Am I missing something?

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSUInteger editIndex = [_athleteArray indexOfObject:_currentAthlete];
    NSUInteger index = editIndex-1;

    Athlete *count = _athleteArray[index];

    NSLog(@"Current Athlete:%@ Index: %lu",count,(unsigned long)index);
}


-(void)whenNextButtonIsTapped{
//stuff
    NSUInteger editIndex = [_athleteArray indexOfObject:_currentAthlete];
    NSUInteger index = editIndex-1;

    Athlete *count = _athleteArray[index];

    NSLog(@"Current Athlete:%@ Index: %lu",count,(unsigned long)index);

    if(index <= ((_athleteArray.count)-1)){
        index++;
        _currentAthlete = _athleteArray[index];
        _evalSelected = [self getMostRecentEval];
        [self updateInformation];
        NSLog(@"Index after being smaller than the array count: %lu",(unsigned long)index);
    }
    else{
        if(index == ((_athleteArray.count)-1)){
            _evalSelected = [self getMostRecentEval];
            [self updateInformation];
            index=0;
            NSLog(@"Index after being equal to array count: %lu",(unsigned long)index);
        }
    }
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Evaluation",_evalSelected.whosEval.full];


}

}


-(Eval *)getMostRecentEval{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whosEval == %@", _currentAthlete];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSEntityDescription *eval = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Eval" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:eval];



    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date_recorded"
                                ascending:NO
                                 selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil){
        //handle error
    }

    NSMutableArray *lastEvalArray = mutableFetchResults;

    return lastEvalArray.firstObject;

}
```

The weird behavior is that a) when view appears, regardless of who is tapped the index is 2. and b) It doesn't go to the next athlete's eval, it is the same guy and it is the last person in the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining editIndex as the index of the currentAthlete. You then subtract 1 from that to get index, then add 1 back to that (with index++), and finally you set currentAthlete to _athleteArray[index], which will be the same athlete you started with. You should be able to fix it by not using index at all, just use editIndex.

Comment: Silliest mistake i've ever made. No idea why that was even there to begin with. Thanks.